# My Xamarin IOS app is causing a SIGABRT crash

Tags: ios, xamarin, sigabrt

My **Xamarin** IOS app is crashing (SIGABRT) . I have a log symbolised report, but am struggling go interpret it. Any help will be much appreciated:

Here is a excerpt of the Symbolized log file:

```
    Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183b0d2ec __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183cb26a8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 360
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183a7bdb0 __abort + 152
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183a7bd18 __abort + 0
4   Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000101fea8a8 xamarin_get_block_descriptor + 4536
5   Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000101f19e98 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 19177112 (exception.c:1119)
6   Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000101edaa88 mono_handle_exception_internal + 18918024 (mini-exceptions.c:2080)
7   Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000101ed97d0 mono_handle_exception + 18913232 (mini-exceptions.c:2371)
8   Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000101ed1da4 mono_arm_throw_exception + 18881956 (exceptions-arm64.c:414)
9   Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000100ffcdb8 throw_exception + 168
10  Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000101fea68c xamarin_get_block_descriptor + 3996
11  Caregiver.iOS                   0x000000010180ea04 wrapper_native_to_managed_ObjCRuntime_Runtime_throw_ns_exception_intptr + 308
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001840871c8 __handleUncaughtException + 828
13  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001832408c8 _objc_terminate+ 35016 () + 112
14  libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018323137c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 111484 ()) + 16
15  libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183231400 std::terminate+ 111616 () + 84
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183978af8 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001839b57a8 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$armv81 + 416
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001839bec20 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 1248
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001839b9c44 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 680
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018402f070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018402cbc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2272
22  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183f4cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
23  GraphicsServices                0x0000000185f2f020 GSEventRunModal + 100
24  UIKit                           0x000000018df2d78c UIApplicationMain + 236
25  Caregiver.iOS                   0x000000010180d6a0 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 368
26  Caregiver.iOS                   0x00000001017a5dbc UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 11361724 (UIApplication.cs:79)
27  Caregiver.iOS                   0x00000001017a5d7c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 11361660 (UIApplication.cs:64)
28  Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000100d0b724 Caregiver_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 243492 (/<unknown>:1)
29  Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000100fc98c8 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 248
30  Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000101ee8fd0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 18976720 (mini-runtime.c:2783)
31  Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000101f50178 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 19399032 (object.c:2887)
32  Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000101f5537c mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 19420028 (object.c:0)
33  Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000101ed15b0 mono_jit_exec + 18879920 (driver.g.c:1210)
34  Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000101ff0d14 xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type + 25552
35  Caregiver.iOS                   0x0000000100cf23e0 main + 140256 (main.m:90)
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001839ddfc0 start + 4
```

The code is basically an input form which allows the user to enter a number of text fields including Text Picker, a time picker and a date picker. The app randomely crashes at different points when filling in the fields.

The XAML code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="Caregiver.NewItemPage"  
             Title="{Binding Itemstatus.Title}"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
              NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             >

       <ContentPage.Resources>  
            <ResourceDictionary>  
              <OnPlatform x:Key="TitleEnable" x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean" Android="true" iOS="true" WinPhone="false"/>  
            </ResourceDictionary>  
       </ContentPage.Resources>  
       <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Save" Clicked="Save_Clicked" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Cancel" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked" />
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout Spacing="2" Padding="2">

                    <!-- Link Button   -->

                    <StackLayout Padding="20,0,20,0">
                        <Grid>
                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                                <Button Text="{Binding Itemstatus.ButTxt} " x:Name="LinkButton"  Clicked="OnLinkButtonClicked" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Accent"/> 
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <!-- Device ID   -->

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,20,10,10">
                                <Label x:Name="IDLabel" Text="Device ID(*)" FontSize="Medium"  FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{Binding Itemstatus.LblColDevice}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  >
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,20,10,0">
                               <Label x:Name = "IDText" Text="{Binding Itemstatus.DeviceID}"  FontSize="Medium"  />
                            </StackLayout>
                         </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <!-- Participant   -->

                     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="10">
                                <Label x:Name = "LblColPtpName" Text="Participant (*) :" FontSize="Medium"  FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{Binding Itemstatus.LblColPtp}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  >

                              <Entry   x:Name="entryInput"  TextChanged="IDEnter_TextChanged" Placeholder="Participant ID Code       " Text="{Binding Itemstatus.Text}" FontSize="Medium"  /> 
                         </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <!-- Country   -->

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="10">
                                 <Label x:Name = "NTimezone" Text="Country (*):       "   FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{Binding Itemstatus.LblColTzs}" />  
                                </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  >
                                <Picker Title="Country                           "  x:Name="PickerCtl" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerCtl_OnSelectedIndexChanged">  
                                    <Picker.Items>  
                                        <x:String>China</x:String> 
                                        <x:String>India</x:String>  
                                         <x:String>Kenya</x:String>  
                                        <x:String>Madagascar</x:String> 
                                        <x:String>South Africa</x:String> 
                                        <x:String>Uganda</x:String>  
                                        <x:String>Vietnam</x:String>  
                                    </Picker.Items>  
                                </Picker> 
                            </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                <!-- Participant Mobile   -->

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="10">
                                <Label x:Name = "LblColMedTimeName" Text="Medication Time(*):" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor = "{Binding Itemstatus.LblColMedTime}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  >
                            <TimePicker Time="{Binding Itemstatus.MedicationTime}"  x:Name="TimeCtl">
                            </TimePicker>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>


                    <StackLayout Padding="10,5,20,0">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  >
                        <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="0">
                             <Label x:Name = "ParMobCol"  Text="Participant Mobile:" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold"  WidthRequest="90" TextColor="{Binding Itemstatus.LblColMobileP}"  />
                        </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  >
                                <Picker Title="Area Code"   x:Name="PickerCtlIntCodeP" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerCtlIntCodeP_OnSelectedIndexChanged" >  
                                    <Picker.Items>  
                                        <x:String>(+86)</x:String>  
                                        <x:String>(+91)</x:String>
                                        <x:String>(+254)</x:String>  
                                        <x:String>(+261)</x:String>  
                                        <x:String>(+27)</x:String>  
                                        <x:String>(+256)</x:String> 
                                    </Picker.Items>  
                                </Picker> 
                         </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  >
                             <Entry  x:Name="entryPInput"  TextChanged="PEnter_TextChanged" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Mobile Number" Text="{Binding Itemstatus.PMobile}"   FontSize="Medium"  WidthRequest="150" /> 
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                     </StackLayout>



                <!-- Reminder Message   -->

                <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,20">
                        <Label x:Name="ReminderMessage" Text="Reminder Message:"  FontSize="Medium"  FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Entry x:Name="entryRInput"  TextChanged="RemEnter_TextChanged" Placeholder="Please remember to take your Medicine" Text="{Binding Itemstatus.Message}"  FontSize="Medium" />
                    </StackLayout>

                <!-- Reminder Options   -->

                    <!-- SMS Reminder - Participant   -->

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,0">
                                <Label Text="Send SMS Reminder to Participant " FontSize="Medium"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Itemstatus.EnableReminderP}"></Switch>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <!-- SMS Reminder Supporter   -->

                     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,0">
                                <Label Text="Send SMS Reminder to Supporter  " FontSize="Medium"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Itemstatus.EnableReminderC}"></Switch> 
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>


                  <!-- Enable Alarm on Dispenser   -->

                   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,0">
                                <Label Text="Enable Alarm on Dispenser              " FontSize="Medium"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Itemstatus.EnableAlarm}"></Switch> 
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>


                   <!-- Date of Birth   -->

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,20,0,0">
                                 <Label x:Name = "DOBCol"  Text="Date of Birth:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{Binding Itemstatus.LblColDOB}"  />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  >
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,10,0,0">
                                <DatePicker x:Name="DateCtl" Format = "dd MMM yyyy" DateSelected="DatePicker_Changed">
                                 </DatePicker>
                            </StackLayout>
                         </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>


                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I have attached a screenshot of the form:
[IOS App Entry Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LkTl.png)

This is the Page code :

```
public NewItemPage(NewItemEViewModel viewModel)
{

    Item = new Item
    {
        Id = viewModel.Itemstatus.Id,
        Text = viewModel.Itemstatus.Text,
        DateOfBirth = viewModel.Itemstatus.DateOfBirth,
        Gender = viewModel.Itemstatus.Gender,
        DeviceID = viewModel.Itemstatus.DeviceID,
        PMobile = viewModel.Itemstatus.PMobile,
        CMobile = viewModel.Itemstatus.CMobile,
        MedicationTime = viewModel.Itemstatus.MedicationTime,
        Message = viewModel.Itemstatus.Message,
        EnableAlarm = viewModel.Itemstatus.EnableAlarm,
        EnableReminderP = viewModel.Itemstatus.EnableReminderP,
        EnableReminderC = viewModel.Itemstatus.EnableReminderC,
        TimeZone = viewModel.Itemstatus.TimeZone,
        Notes = viewModel.Itemstatus.Notes,
        IntCodeP = viewModel.Itemstatus.IntCodeP,
        IntCodeC = viewModel.Itemstatus.IntCodeC
    };

    if (viewModel.Itemstatus.DeviceID == "No Device Linked") viewModel.Itemstatus.ButTxt = "Link Device "; else viewModel.Itemstatus.ButTxt = " Unlink Device ";

    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;

    PickerCtl.SelectedIndex = viewModel.Itemstatus.TimezoneIndex;
    PickerCtlGender.SelectedIndex = viewModel.Itemstatus.GenderIndex;
    PickerCtlIntCodeP.SelectedIndex = viewModel.Itemstatus.IntCodePIndex;
    PickerCtlIntCodeC.SelectedIndex = viewModel.Itemstatus.IntCodeCIndex;

    DateCtl.Date = viewModel.Itemstatus.DateOfBirth;
    DateCtl.MaximumDate = System.DateTime.Now.Date;

}
```

Comment: What is the app doing at the point where it crashes?  Can you provide the code executing at the time the crash happens?

Comment: Hi Peter , The app is running a form which accepts text fields, a number of Picker fields and switches. The app randomly crashes either as a switch is changed or while the date picker is selected or spun.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have added some more detail to the issue above, including the XAML code

Comment: Your XAML looks well. The issue may be caused by your code behind. Can you share a whole simple sample?

Comment: Hi Peter. I have added the Page code that runs with this XAML. There are some procedures but the crash happens before any of them are called.

Comment: I ran the app many times to try and understand the trigger for the crash. What ive noticed is that if I fill the form in without touching the switch buttons, I cannot get the app to crash. After using the switch, the crash occurs about 4 seconds later. Using the switch doesnt always crash the app however.

Answer (score 0):

After trying absolutely everything, I replaced the Buttons (Switches) with Item Pickers. This stopped the app from crashing randomly.

I am not sure why the buttons/switches cause instability.